# Creating a full ISO image of Ubuntu from console

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, iso-image

I would like to know if it is possible to create a full ISO image of an existing Ubuntu system from the console, and how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html). From the web page:

> Remastersys is a tool that can be used to do 2 things with an existing Debian,  Ubuntu or derivative installation. 
>      It can make **a full system backup including personal data to a live cd** or dvd that you can use anywhere and install. 
>      It can make **a distributable copy you can share with friends**.  This will not have any of your personal user data in it.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Remastersys is not a console tool , It is a gui tool